# How can I store dates/attendance?

Tags: php, database, date, storage

I'm looking for for an opinion.

I have a list of people and will need to store when they are present at a location so those in charge can check them off a list. I'm not 100% sure how long the dates will be needed but I'm assuming they may need to look at previous attendance lists.

My first instinct is to have a column for each date but that could result in many many columns. I could just store a list of dates next to each person:

"01/01/2012,01/15/2012,02/18/2012..."

that could result in a very long entry. It seems like neither is a good option.

If anyone has a suggestion or guidance on an approach please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Using one column to store a list of data is nearly always a bad decision. There is no efficient query to get datasets based on a date filter (in your case). Neals way in the answers below is the right point to start.

Answer (score 2):

A complex, but also very clean approach would be

Table "persons":

- id
- name

Table "dates":

- id
- location
- date
- ... whatever info the "dates" table needs

Table "attendances":

- date_id (link to an entry in the "dates" table)
- person_id (link to an entry in the "persons" table)
- attended (yes/no)

Then fill the database with the appropriate dates, and fill the "attendances" table according to which persons need to be present at each date.

This is, as said, complex  to implement, but it's incredibly flexible - you can have any number of dates and attendees; you can excuse people from attending a specific date programmatically; you can add people to groups...

Comment: I did something similar for another project. Maybe I'll use the approach again. Seems like that's the way to go. Only concern is the date_id will duplicate in the column. 15 attendees would mean the date_id will be there 15 times.

Comment: @dcp but that wouldn't really be a problem, would it? Unless you're storing billions of dates maybe....

Comment: My concern was the dates wouldn't be set by the users. Meaning they could have a "class" at any given day at any given time. After some prodding it seems they times are set for 4 month period then they change. So this option may work. Happily it's close to a setup I was thinking about using.

Answer (score 1):

Link tables.

One table of people

- ID
- Name

One table of classes

- ID
- Name

One table linking person to class to date.

- ID
- personID
- classID
- cDate

So all you would need to do to determine which students were preset on a certain date in a certain class:

```
SELECT *
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN peopletoclass ptc ON p.id = ptc.personid
LEFT join class c ON c.id = ptc.classid
WHERE ptc.cDate = '2011-11-07' AND c.id = '1';
```

Above (for example) would get all people in class id 1 on November 7th 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table "`attendance`" consisting of a `person_id` field and a `date_present` field. You can't store this into columns or a long list using a string ;-).

Than you can use queries where you join the table `Person` with `Attendance`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first instinct would result in a horrible table design. What you should have is a seperate table that stores the users/locations/dates tuples

e.g.

```
userID   locationID   date

1       party          1/1/2011 00:00:00
1       bathroom       1/1/2011 00:05:00
1       party          1/1/2011 00:15:00
```

would show that user #1 was at a New Year's Eve party, then went to pray before the porcelain altar at 12:05am, then returned to the party 10 minutes later.